# mapping EF entities to BL objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF DB first in my solution.

I have `BL`, `DAL` and `Common` Layers.

`BL` contains a manager that manipulate the business model

`Dal` does CRUD operations

The later keeps all the DTOs and interfaces which all other layers consume.

Every project references the `Common` project.

Now I want to create `IDal` interface which returns a list of my `Business model` object (Of EF type)

The thing is that the EF types are defined in the Dal project and this reference Common\IDal

So IDal cannot refernce Dal as due to circular reference.

I thought to map the EF object to BL object, but then how can I make it efficient?

I have many composed `Business model` objects. I don't want to duplicate them.

right?

Comment: 1. Why would you map EF entities to business objects? You can extend the entities because they are partial classes. You only have to make sure that you don't use non-mapped properties in linq-to-entities queries. 2. The role of this `IDal` is not clear to me. Is it some sort of a repository?

Comment: My Dal does CRUD operation. As a good practice every concrete class should be wrapped by an interfece, `Dal : IDal`

Answer (score -1):

I think the IDAL should be in Common or in DAL itself.

There is no need to create many project whenever you want to reference a project.

You can change the visibility of your repositories if you have to `internal` so that other project would be able to consume just `public` interfaces.

For more alternative and different implementations I think [NSK Starter Kit](http://nsk.codeplex.com) would be a very good reference.

**Update 1:**

The structure should be as below:

- The central part of project which
  contains almost all you pure business is `Domain`.
- There is a `Data Access` below which references `Domain`
- There would be a `Data Access Common` which contains `Data Access Interfaces`
- There is a `Service` project maybe which contains more complex operations which involve more that one aggregate object, which references the `Domain` and `Data Access Interface`
- There is a `Service Interface` which contains `Service Interface and DTO`s
- And There is a `UI` which references the `Service Interface` and probably `Domain`.

Even you can take a look at my own crafted structure at [Cedar](https://github.com/jzinedine/Cedar)

Comment: We create the common project so no compilation is required to all the cnsumer of IDal, when the implementation changes. This is loosely coupling

Comment: Yes, I know about it dude, so I didn't understand the problem correctly, If your team is not big enough these kind of things is mostly ceremony, anyway let me update the answer.

Comment: Mixing business object with DAL would be the dumbest decision, so what the BL project contains?